# SQL Pivot query without aggregation or max

Tags: sql-server, pivot

I am trying to get a pivot result with no aggregation, I tried max and it didn't help, may be I am doing something wrong.

When I run this below query

```
declare @t table 
(
    col1 int,
    col2 varchar(100),
    col3 varchar(100),
    col4 varchar(100),
    col5 int
)

insert into @t values(1,'test1','p1','v1',1)
insert into @t values(1,'test1','p2','v2',2)
insert into @t values(1, 'test1','p3','v3',3)
insert into @t values(1,'test1','p1','v11',1)
insert into @t values(1,'test1','p1','v12',1)
insert into @t values(1,'test1','p2','v21',2)
insert into @t values(1,'test1','p2','v22',2)

--select * from @t
select col1,
    col2, 
    [p1],
    [p2],
    [p3]
from 
(
    select * from @t
) x
pivot
(
    Max(col4 )
    for col3 in ([p1],[p2],[p3])
) pvt
```

I get this below result

[image]

I am trying to get this below result

[image]

It would be great if you could show me a path to achieve this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll still need to use an aggregate function with the PIVOT, but you need some sort of value to return multiple rows based on the combination of `col1`, `col2`, and `col3`.  This is where you'd want to use a windowing function like `row_number()`.

If you use the following query you should be able to get the result:

```
select col1, col2, p1, p2, p3
from 
(
  select col1, col2, col3, col4, 
    rn = row_number() over(partition by col1, col2, col3 order by col5, col4)
  from @t
) d
pivot
(
  max(col4)
  for col3 in (p1, p2, p3)
) p;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/42103)

The `row_number()` function creates a unique sequence that is partitioned by the `col1`, `col2` and `col3` values - I then ordered the results by your `col5` and `col4` values to create the sequence in a specific order.   This new value is used when the pivot groups the data which results in multiple rows being returned instead of the single row.